# How to enable image search in Google Custom Search API

Tags: json, rest, api, google-api

Please help me with `GET` request parameters.

The problem: How to enable image search in Google Custom Search API?

The manual is [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest), but it woks only for web search.

For example doing a web search with text **flowers** returns:

```
{https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={MY-KEY}&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json}
```

Image search should have the extra parameter `searchType=image`

```
{https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={MY-KEY}&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&searchType=image&alt=json}
```

But it returns JSON with 0 search results.

Please tell me what I’m doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enabled in the search engine configuration (disabled by default). I also spent some time on why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, then I tried to configure the search engine and it worked afterwards

1. Go to "programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/all"
2. FInd your using engine and click
3. The website will navigate to the control panel
4. "Overview -> Search function"
5. Turn on "image search" and "search the entire web

Refer to the image below:

[image: Like this, you maybe need to turn on "image search" and "Search the entire web" option]

Comment: Could you add in text the configuration settings to change, as images aren't accessible to everyone.

Comment: My pologize

1. Go to "https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/all"

2. FInd your using engine and click

3. The website will navigate to the control panel

4. "Overview -> Search function"

5. Turn on "image search" and "search the entire web"

Answer (score 0):

I used the API Explorer to emulate a search and got the corrected URL that way

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={QUERY}&cx={CX}&{OPTIONS}={VALUES}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&searchType=image&alt=json
```

As silly as it sounds, apparently the exact order matters for it to work.